# ffmpeg lists dar and sar twice

Tags: ffmpeg, rendering, resolution

My source video stream has these parameters:

```
Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 1548 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 2997 tbn, 5994 tbc
```

My goal is to get video stream with such parameters:

```
SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9
```

After rendering video stream has this output:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 512x288 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 173 kb/s, SAR 4:3 DAR 64:27, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 2997 tbn, 47.95 tbc
```

As a result my video displays with incorrect parameters.
I'm wondering what causes these SAR 4:3 DAR 64:27 and how can I avoid it.

Comment: It seems to me that you have 2 streams now. Could you have converted this to an interleaved version?
And of course 64:27 = 16:9 * 4:3, so it seems DAR is multiplied iso SAR divided to do the scaling on the second stream.

Comment: @Pieter21 
"ffmpeg -i" outputs only the single video stream, and it's not seems to me as interleaved

Comment: What does `ffprobe -v quiet -show_streams movie_file.mp4` show in terms of the number of streams?

Comment: @deadcode, it shows the only one stream